# Ненадолго разлука, всего лишь на миг

Tags: грамматика, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, члены-предложения

Практически во всех текстах Б. Окуджавы можно увидеть слитное написание наречия ***ненадолго:***

***Ненадолго разлука, всего лишь на миг, а потом***

***Отправляться и нам по следам по его по горячим.***

Но мне кажется, что здесь **НЕ должно писаться раздельно по следующим причинам:**

1) в тексте есть противопоставление, хотя союз А отсутствует (не надолго, а на миг);

2) препозиция наречия **с логическим выделением его  голосом** (что можно определить при прослушивании песни).

**Вопросы:**

1) Какое написание **вам кажется более правильным** (по правилам допускаются оба).http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81

2) Вам встречались варианты текста с раздельным написанием частицы НЕ?

2) ***Ненадолго разлука.*** Как разобрать это предложение (какова функция наречия)?  Есть ли здесь инверсия? (Обычно инверсия делается для выделения нужного слова логическим ударением).

Comment: Второй вопрос не может иметь ответа, не так ли?

Comment: Почему не может? Я спрашиваю о существовании вариантов текста, разве это невозможно?  Мне кажется,что отрицание с противопоставлением подходит больше. Если слитное письмо считать авторским вариантом, то могли быть и отклонения от него.  Я думаю, что Окуджава вряд ли хорошо разбирался в тонкостях орфографии (он поэт, и это не его тема).

Comment: «Я спрашиваю о существовании вариантов текста...». Вы спросили о всех текстах песни! Предлагаете отыскать их все?

Comment: Пожалуй, не стоит. Уж лучше  я изменю формулировку вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

> в тексте есть противопоставление, хотя союз А отсутствует (не надолго,
>   а на миг);

1)Здесь нет противопоставления. "а потом" - это совершенно доугая часть фразы, она скорее усиливает "ненадолго", чем противопоставляет. 
Противопоставление это когда есть антоним или хотя бы его контекстный эквивалент: ***не надолго, а всего лишь на день-два***. 
Да, противопоставление - не исключительный мотив для раздельного написания, но остальное - это уже авторские прибамбасы, из серии "Я художник - я так вижу".

> 2) препозиция наречия с логическим выделением его голосом (что можно
>   определить при прослушивании песни).

Не слышу такого. А если оно и есть, это на что-то влияет?
Чтобы подчеркнуть это "противопоставление" или что там еще может оправдатььь раздельное написание надо как-то очень по-особому произнести это "ненадолго": отрывисто, с ударением на частице... В песню это не ляжет, а для Окуджавы - с его-то лирической плавностью и переливами текста -  вообще не свойственно.

Вообще надо сильно постараться, чтобы увидеть тут мотивы для раздельного написания.
Так что ответ на основной вопрос однозначен. По смыслу, по стилистике Окуджавы, по общему контексту - слитно и только так.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение, для меня  оно всегда интересно. Логическое ударение не может падать на частицу, оно падает на слово, перед которым стоит частица НЕ: не надОлго. Это я слышу при исполнении песни. О связи логического ударения и раздельного написания говорит Розенталь, например: "В вопросительном предложении при логическом подчеркивании отрицания частица НЕ с предикативным наречием пишется раздельно: Не удивительно ли, что посредственное произведение так разрекламировано"?

Comment: *Логическое ударение не может падать на частицу, оно падает на слово, перед которым стоит частица НЕ: не надОлго.* - Поєтому я и сказал, что здесь слитно. ))) А чтобы подчергнуть голосом раздельное написание, надо перенести его на частицу. Что весьма затруднительно вообще - а в песне тем более.

Comment: Не удивИтельно ли .... Это пример из Розенталя, логическое подчеркивания отрицания, по его словам,  присутствует, но ударение падает не на частицу НЕ, а на логически подчеркнутое наречие.

Comment: Какой пример  "из Розенталя"?! Мы разбираем пример "из Окуджавы".   О чем речь вообще? Вы не согласны, с тем, что для оправдания раздельного написания ("не надолго") автору надо акцент перевести на частицу? Вообще несогласны или только в этом случае? По мне так в этом и есть суть этого орфографического правила. И чтобы это было понятно на слух, надо очень сильно постараться. Потому что такой смысл весьма необычен - чтобы не сказать "противоестественен" - для этого наречия...

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за ответ,  но мне кажется, что не стоит углубляться в эту тему. Я всего лишь высказала свое понимание орфографии, а вы не согласились с ним, и я  уважаю Ваше мнение. Чтобы здесь разобраться в деталях, нужно  предварительно обсудить еще очень многое, а это вряд ли возможно в пределах  одного вопроса.